# How to Implement Clustering Function on AODV Network of OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I want to implement clustering function on AODV network. Preliminary consideration is given to clustering based on calculating the distance between nodes and the number of neighboring nodes. But after my reflection, how can the clustering algorithm be implemented in OMNeT++, in AODV.cc? Or where? This is very confusing to me. I'm not sure if anyone can provide some help. Below is the code for the AODV protocol initialization section, and I'm not sure if it's useful

```
void Aodv::initialize(int stage)
```

{
if (stage == INITSTAGE_ROUTING_PROTOCOLS)
addressType = getSelfIPAddress().getAddressType(); // needed for handleStartOperation()

```
RoutingProtocolBase::initialize(stage);

if (stage == INITSTAGE_LOCAL) {
    lastBroadcastTime = SIMTIME_ZERO;
    rebootTime = SIMTIME_ZERO;
    rreqId = sequenceNum = 0;
    rreqCount = rerrCount = 0;
    host = getContainingNode(this);
    routingTable.reference(this, "routingTableModule", true);
    interfaceTable.reference(this, "interfaceTableModule", true);
    networkProtocol.reference(this, "networkProtocolModule", true);

    aodvUDPPort = par("udpPort");
    askGratuitousRREP = par("askGratuitousRREP");
    useHelloMessages = par("useHelloMessages");
    destinationOnlyFlag = par("destinationOnlyFlag");
    activeRouteTimeout = par("activeRouteTimeout");
    helloInterval = par("helloInterval");
    allowedHelloLoss = par("allowedHelloLoss");
    netDiameter = par("netDiameter");
    nodeTraversalTime = par("nodeTraversalTime");
    rerrRatelimit = par("rerrRatelimit");
    rreqRetries = par("rreqRetries");
    rreqRatelimit = par("rreqRatelimit");
    timeoutBuffer = par("timeoutBuffer");
    ttlStart = par("ttlStart");
    ttlIncrement = par("ttlIncrement");
    ttlThreshold = par("ttlThreshold");
    localAddTTL = par("localAddTTL");
    jitterPar = &par("jitter");
    periodicJitter = &par("periodicJitter");

    myRouteTimeout = par("myRouteTimeout");
    deletePeriod = par("deletePeriod");
    blacklistTimeout = par("blacklistTimeout");
    netTraversalTime = par("netTraversalTime");
    nextHopWait = par("nextHopWait");
    pathDiscoveryTime = par("pathDiscoveryTime");
    expungeTimer = new cMessage("ExpungeTimer");
    counterTimer = new cMessage("CounterTimer");
    rrepAckTimer = new cMessage("RrepAckTimer");
    blacklistTimer = new cMessage("BlackListTimer");
    if (useHelloMessages)
        helloMsgTimer = new cMessage("HelloMsgTimer");
}
else if (stage == INITSTAGE_ROUTING_PROTOCOLS) {
    networkProtocol->registerHook(0, this);
    host->subscribe(linkBrokenSignal, this);
    usingIpv6 = (routingTable->getRouterIdAsGeneric().getType() == L3Address::IPv6);
}
```

}

Comment: How does a node get to know the distance to another node?

Comment: What I'm thinking is that there is a getCurrentPosition method in the node's mobility model? Can you help me think about where the clustering algorithm would be implemented in the AODV example (we won't consider the clustering metrics for now)

Comment: Simulation reflects real network and in real network a node doesn't know geographical positions of other nodes. One may use `getCurrentPosition()` to obtain only **own** position. Could you precise what is expected result of clustering in your network?

Comment: The expected result I want to achieve is clustering based on AODV, where all nodes are divided into several clusters in the AODV network. Similar to the following article https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9987222